# how to create and execute a sagemaker pipeline via lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

based on the docs, I want to create a sagemaker pipeline with register model step ( sample below) and execute it via lambda. are there any examples. i need to download the existing model.tar.gz file and repackage and register it .

```
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.inputs import CreateModelInput
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import CreateModelStep
from sagemaker.model_metrics import MetricsSource, ModelMetrics
from sagemaker.workflow.step_collections import RegisterModel

model = Model(
    image_uri=image_uri, # the XGBoost image
    model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts, # The S3 location of the 'model.tar.gz' file
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    role=role,
)

inputs = CreateModelInput(
    instance_type="ml.m5.large",
    accelerator_type="ml.eia1.medium",
)

step_create_model = CreateModelStep(
    name="adultCreateModel",
    model=model,
    inputs=inputs,
)

step_register = RegisterModel(
    name="adultRegisterModel",
    estimator=xgb_train,
    model_data=step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts, # The S3 uri to the 'model.tar.gz' file
    content_types=["text/csv"],
    response_types=["text/csv"],
    inference_instances=["ml.t2.medium", "ml.m5.xlarge"],
    transform_instances=["ml.m5.xlarge"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this blog for guidance on creating a SageMaker Pipeline using Lambda - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-a-sagemaker-pipeline-lambda-step-for-lightweight-model-deployments/